# Integrating Determinants of Hessian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I was reading N. V. Krylov's book "Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Sobolev Spaces" and decided to work through some of the exercises I left behind and got easily stuck on

> **3. Exercise** By using the Fourier transform, prove that, if $d = 2$ and $u \in C^2_0$, then 
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \det u_{xx} dx =0 $$

I can show this using integration by parts and an approximation by polynomial argument, but I am unsure where to use the Fourier transform. I have tried the following:

> By Parseval's identity and the exchange formula we have 
>   $$ \|u_{xy}\|_2^2 = \|\tilde{u}_{xy}\|_2^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \xi_1^2\xi_2^2 |\tilde{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi_1d\xi_2$$
>   which kind of deals with the $u_{xy}$ term, but this probably leads to nowhere.

Somewhere in the argument I have to use the fact that $u$ is compactly supported, but I am not sure how.

On a related note, the book has a section on "Integrating the determinants of Hessians" which I skipped, but looking back it seemed quite interesting. Unfortunately I was not able to find any source online that connects the exercise

> **1. Exercise** Let $\Omega$ be a connected bounded domain with smooth boundary and let $F, G: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be $C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ mappings such that $F = G$ on $\partial \Omega$, then 
>   $$ \int_{\Omega} \det \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx = \int_{\Omega} \det \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} dx$$

to the theory of nonlinear PDEs (as mentioned in the book, but no reference is given whatsoever). I am guessing this has to do with certain Monge–Ampère equations. Any reference on this and any hint on the first exercise will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: The compact support assumption is just there to ensure that the Fourier transform is well behaved (i.e. all formal manipulations are justified). To solve the exercise write $2u_{xx} u_{yy} =(\Delta u) ^2-u_{xx}^2-u_{yy}^2$ and take the Fourier transform.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First exercise:

$$\int u_{xx} u_{yy} dxdy = c \int \xi_1^2 \hat{u}(\xi) \xi_2^2 \hat{u}(\xi) d \xi_1 d\xi_2 = c\int \xi_1 \xi_2  \hat{u}(\xi) \xi_1 \xi_2 \hat{u}(\xi) d \xi_1 d\xi_2 = \int u_{xy} u_{xy} dxdy.$$

Second exercise:

So far I just think of some possible solution, which I am not totally sure.
Set $\vec{H}:=\vec{F}- \vec{G}.$
Construct some $C_0^2 (\Omega)$ function $\varphi$ such that $\vec{H} =\nabla \varphi$ in $\Omega.$
For instance, consider the problem 
$$ \Delta \varphi = div \vec H \,\,\,\text{in} \,\,\,\Omega, 
\quad  \varphi =0 \,\,\,\text{on} \,\,\,\partial \Omega.$$

Then if the first exercise holds for general dimension $d \geq 2,$ then we end up with 
$$0 =\int_{\Omega} \det (\nabla^2 \varphi) dx  
= \int_{\Omega} \det(\nabla^{\top}\vec{H})dx
=\int_{\Omega} \det(\nabla^{\top}\vec{F})dx - \int_{\Omega} \det(\nabla^{\top}\vec{G})dx.$$

Comment: For the second exercise, Krylov has a detailed hint which I am sure works (I didn't type it because it's lengthy). The idea is to introduce $F_t = F(x) + tx$ and $G_t = G(x) + tx$ and deduce that the images of $\Omega$ under $F_t$ and $G_t$ have the same volume. Express the volume in terms of the Jacobian of $F_t$ and $G_t$. In fact this exercise is used to show that the first exercise is true for all $d \ge 2$.